# How to print data in PDF when I'm using Java EE technology?

Tags: pdf, printing, struts2, pdf-generation, reporting

I have a `Person` class with `name`, `national_Id`, `age`, `photo` and `job` as member variables and I want to print some kind of voucher or FICHE with the personal data of each person.
I don't want to use the JavaScript print window function, I want to print it as PDF. I'm using JEE: Struts+Hibernate.

Comment: [Struts2 Display pdf file in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11138664/456135)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use itext pdf to print the data to a pdf file..

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html

and then go through this link..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11138664/456135